# How to disable Directory Listing?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

From what I can read changing

```
Options All Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

to

```
Options All FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

in `httpd.conf` should disable directory listing, but I can still list them.

I have only been able to disable this using `.htaccess` files.

**Question**

How do I disable directory listing in `httpd.conf` for `DocumentRoot` and all `VirtualHost`'s?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it doesn't work like that, the `All` means enable all options except `MultiViews`, the order is also important. To disable directory listings you need `-Indexes` so

```
Options All FollowSymLinks MultiViews -Indexes
```

would work but

```
Options -Indexes All FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

wouldn't as the `All` after the `-Indexes` would re-enable it.

Answer (score 4):

You should put this on your httpd.conf to disable indexes globally:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Then you should check all your virtual hosts to see if they have it explicitly enabled.

This [blog post](http://www.ducea.com/2006/06/26/apache-tips-tricks-disable-directory-indexes/) might be helpful to understand how directory listing works.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `All` from the flags, as well.  `All` sets every option to enabled, except for `MultiViews`.